# Why Output FPDF Like This?

Tags: php, laravel, web, fpdf

I'm install fpdf in laravel, i get success installation, but when i'm running this program to get pdf the output was not correctly (i tried to run basic example), has anyone experienced the same case?

My reference : https://github.com/codedge/laravel-fpdf

Output : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prFU1.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think the output is a correct pdf file data . But you should tell the system to output the stream as a PDF file.

Assuming the pdf is stored in $data, then

```
  header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
  header("Content-disposition: attachment;filename=YOURFILE.pdf");
  echo $data;
```